# Array not separating category ids in WordPress 'tax_query'

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have the following code and its not working because the array is not responding as expected. I am creating category selection on WordPress metabox and stored in the database as serialized data but when using `tax_query` to fetch the selected categories, the array fails for separated the category id in the `terms` field. Check the code below:

```
$selected_categories = get_post_meta($post->ID, $prefix . 'services_category', true);
if ($selected_categories != '') {
    $categories = unserialize(get_post_custom($post->ID)[$prefix . 'services_category'][0]);
}

$cat_query = '';
$cat_query =  ( !empty($categories) ) ? implode(',', $categories) : '';

if ($cat_query != '') {
    $tax_query = array(
            array(
            'taxonomy' => 'services_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array($cat_query),
            ),
        );
} else { $tax_query = null; }




$services_paged = is_front_page() ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : get_query_var( 'paged' );
query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'mt-services',
    'posts_per_page' => $services,
    'paged' => $services_paged,
    'tax_query' => $tax_query
));
```

Here is where my question lies: I'm trying to echo the selected categories from metabox but unfortunately they are all echoed as one item.

```
'terms' => array($cat_query)
```

Here's the result:

```
print_r(array($cat_query)
```

gives me

```
Array ( [0] => 73,72 )
```

instead of

```
Array ( [0] => 73, [1] => 72 )
```

**Detailed explanation**

`$categories` values are 73 and 72.

Using implode function we get `$cat_query which` is `(73,72)`.

Hence the `array($cat_query)` would be `array(73,72)` which when printed out should be:

```
Array ( [0] => 73, [1] => 72 )
```

But instead, $cat_query values are taken as a unit which ends up being printed out as:

```
Array ( [0] => 73,72 )
```

which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

`$cat_query` is created from `$categories` with the function implode.
So I assume that `$categories` is an array that looks like the one you want:

```
Array ( [0] => 73, [1] => 72 )
```

Comment: You are right but $categories is already unserialized data and its values are 73 and 72. I have edited the question. Kindly check.

Comment: I dont' know what you exactly want, but I assume you want to convert the imploded array back. Using the implode function it returns the different array values as one string. When you then use `array($cat_query)` it only inserts one element into the array. If you want to seperate them again use: `explode(',', $cat_query)`